# Is it possible to carousel the button template in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

**I need help.**

I have a mock-up here that shows the **carousel button template** sample.

**[Sample (assuming) button carousel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sMR.png)**

I do read the documentation but only **[generic template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic)** can do the carousel.

Here's the example of **[generic template carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMxvd.png)**

Is it possible to have carousel button template or not?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create carousel od cards containing only buttons. This is not possible, as generic template card has to contain title. Rest of the fields are optional. You can check it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/templates/generic)

Solution nearest to your needs is to create cards with title and buttons.